# background Service being Killed due to another Apps background Service

Tags: java, android

when i start my apps service while keeping another apps background service it crashes any solution?

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.babluboro.urecorder, PID: 11644
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.babluboro.urecorder.RecordingService@3db08eb with Intent { cmp=com.example.babluboro.urecorder/.RecordingService }: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1924)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:943)
        at com.example.babluboro.urecorder.RecordingService.startRecording(RecordingService.java:124)
        at com.example.babluboro.urecorder.RecordingService.onStartCommand(RecordingService.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4128)

Comment: When you start record process (by invoking .start() method) it's interface been block by system. So any other process couldn't use same interface. Unfortunately it's made by Android design so you need to check if it is busy.

Comment: how to check it if other apps service is running ??